# TypeError: MagicLoginStrategy is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I was following the tutorial on https://github.com/mxstbr/passport-magic-login, but it keeps yelling at me "TypeError: MagicLoginStrategy is not a constructor" when running the code. Following is my code.

```
@auth.js
import MagicLoginStrategy from "passport-magic-login"

const magicLogin = new MagicLoginStrategy({...});
export default magicLogin;

@app.js
import magicLogin from './auth.js';
...
passport.use(magicLogin);
```

Why does it keep yelling the error? I also checked the MagicLoginStrategy, it was as follows.

```
class MagicLoginStrategy {
    private _options;
    ...
    constructor(_options: Options);
    ...
}
export default MagicLoginStrategy;
```

I think i'm calling the right constructor, and I don't know why I'm facing the errors.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import MagicLoginStrategy from "passport-magic-login";

const magicLogin = new MagicLoginStrategy.default();
```

It's loading the CommonJS dist file instead of the ESM file.

Comment: Another quick qeustion, how do i know if i'm loading the esm file or commonjs file??

Comment: @June1010 I don't actually know if you can see the difference, I just looked at how the package was configured :)

Answer (score 0):

const MagicLoginStrategy = require('passport-magic-login').default

there is an issue about it
https://github.com/mxstbr/passport-magic-login/issues/7 ;